# When does the predicate `identifier?` returns `#t` in Racket

Tags: racket

I see a predicate `identifier?` in racket but as the picture bellow shows, it seems to never return the true value.

[image]

I went through the docs ([here](https://docs.racket-lang.org/predicates/index.html)) but it seems there's no info on this particular predicate. does anyone know what's the use of this procedure and when does it return true?

Comment: You were in the wrong part of the docs: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxops.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstx..rkt%29._identifier~3f%29%29

Comment: I googled it in too many ways but never find this page. thanks. @ScottHunter

Comment: @AshkanKhademian Don't google, use the search function in the Racket documentation.